# Javascript CRUD with local file and no server

Tags: javascript, json, database, sqlite, indexeddb

I'm trying to build a small "webapp", that should run only in a browser, with no access to internet or a server. It's a small program I am going to use at my job, where I should store information about users.

It's basically described a small "CRUD project", where I have to store information about users in a local file. I don't think I can use LocalStorage, because I need to store the data in an external file, if the user clears the browser cache, all the data is gone.

I was thinking about `JavaScript/JSON`, `JavaScript/SQLite` or `JavaScript/IndexedDB`. But as far as I can read, they need some kind of server to work or don't have a local file.

I don't have Windows administrator rights at work, so I need to use simple files without installation of further software etc.

Do you have any suggestions about what technologies I might look at?

The program should contain something like:

```
index.html
style.css
script.js
database.db
```

I can build it with local, so if there is some way of making the storage into a file, that might also be a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Origin private file system](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API/Origin_private_file_system) might be helpful

Comment: Clearing the browser cache does not clear local storage.